# How to obtain statespace having two inputs from transfer function in matlab mfile

Tags: matlab

I have a transfer function with two zeros and four poles:

```
G(s)=   (as^2+bs+c)/(s^4+ds^3+es^2 )
```

Where a,b,c,d and e are the constants and 's' is for laplace transform.

I need to convert the Transfer function to statespace such that it has two inputs

*i.e.* matrix B has two columns.

I know the commands tf2ss in MatLab MFile but it gives me statespace with one input. The space state equations which I will obtain from this TF; I have to use them in space state block of simulink. I have to give two inputs to this block. How can I do that? any guidance.

Comment: G(s), as you have written it, cannot have two inputs. If it had, you wouldn't be able to write it in s-domain.

Comment: note that `as` does not represent `a*s` in matlab but simply a new variable. Furthermore I am not sure what `s` is but you might need to use the elementwise `.^` operator rather than the matrix operator `^`.

I think the easiest way to help you would be if you could show a small example of what you want the inputs and outputs to be.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, Shayan Ali probably did it like this: Gs = tf([a b c],[1 d e 0 0]). s is not just any other variable. It is a complex number which originates from Laplace transform.

Comment: Can you kindly explain me that if I want to define two inputs why I can't do that in s-domain.

Comment: A transfer function is the relation between a system's outputs and inputs. If you have two inputs and one output, you need two transfer functions relating your output to each input.

Comment: I may have described the problem incorrectly in my first comment. You either need to write it in state space or have a matrix of s-domain transfer functions.

Comment: This article may help: http://seit.unsw.adfa.edu.au/staff/sites/hrp/papers/pota96a-j.pdf